# Spring boot security on Camel Rest DSL

Tags: rest, spring-security, apache-camel

I am a rookie at spring boot , I just want to know that if it is possible to apply spring boot security for camel rest-dsl impls'.

Camel rest dsl is serving over its own servlet as I have seen (CamelHttpTransportServlet) but spring has its own servlet (DispatcherServlet). So ,as I have guessed ,spring security , by default , serves over DispatcherServlet based rest services.

Any way to apply this privileges over camel's own servlet with just a config or should it be checked inside a route with a bean that if it is authorized to enter or not?

I can use other security credentials like camel-security or camel's spring-security samples but my question is not that as you can see :)

thx

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security is implemented with Filters, so yes, it is definitely possible. Spring Security doesn't really know about DispatcherServlet, it could be used for non SpringMVC applications too. 
There's actually a Spring Boot [Camel Example here](http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html) that you could easily add any security with Spring Security as far as you're using the HTTP transport. I.E. you can retrofit this [old spring security camel example](http://camel.apache.org/spring-security-example.html) to Spring Boot and Spring Security using the Spring Security DSL.